# Merge two pairs in the same array if the pairs have the same value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, keyvaluepair

I have the following pairs and they are in the same array:

```
[
 ["ID" => 0, "User" => "Test" , "Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"],
 ["ID" => 1, "User" => "Test1", "Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"],
 ["ID" => 2, "User" => "Test2", "Type" => 4, "Target" => "Shirone"],
 ["ID" => 3, "User" => "Test3", "Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"]
]
```

I want to get the kinds of them, so I using the following code:

```
$SortList = [];

foreach($Notif as $Key => $Value)
            array_push($SortList, ['Type'   => $Value['Type'], 
                                   'Target' => $Value['Target']]);
```

and get this:

```
[
 ["Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"], 
 ["Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"], 
 ["Type" => 4, "Target" => "Shirone"],
 ["Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"]
]
```

**But what I really want is something like this:**

```
[
 ["Type" => 3, "Target" => "Caris"], 
 ["Type" => 4, "Target" => "Shirone"]
]
```

I want to merge the pairs if they were same value,

(`array_merge()` seems can only used for non-pair)

How can I merge them like something above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SortList = [];
foreach($Notif as $Key => $Value) {
    // Just save only value for the same pair, use them concatenated as the key
    $SortList[$Value['Type']."_".$Value['Target']] =
      array('Type' => $Value['Type'], 'Target' => $Value['Target']);
}
// remove extra stuff (the keys) that was added to prevent duplicates
$SortList = array_values($SortList);
```

Comment: You should probably explain what you are doing and how it is different that what they are doing.

Comment: And you only need `$SortList[$Value['Type']]`.  Don't over complicate it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: maybe there are different Targets for the same Type

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn: thanks, added inline comments. It's no rocket science, hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ummm, using the same key to avoid them repeat, genius,

I thought there's a function can handle this, never mind,

just learned this trick.